# unwrap_or in rust that returns two values?

Tags: rust

How do I write a function like this:

```
pub fn unwrap_some_or_none_with_error(input: Option<&'static str>) -> &str {
    input.unwrap_or(0)
}
```

So that when None is sent to this function it will return `0`, and when an Option like `Some` is sent it unwraps it ?

Comment: That's what `unwrap_or` does. The issue here is that your types make no sense: the function is supposed to return an `&str` but your `unwrap_or` has an *integer* default. `0` is not a string.

Comment: That's what I am asking, I want it to return the unwrap result or if none then return 0. Is that possible?

Comment: No it's not since as I noted the types don't match. `0` is an integer, an integer is not a string, your function is typed to return strings. `"0"` would work fine but I've no idea why you'd want to return such a thing.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the `0` once it's unwrapped? There may be a more idiomatic way to do what you want, but it's not obvious from the question what that might be. For example, you could handle the two cases in two branches of a match, or in a closure attached to a method on the`Option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible: Rust is a typed language so everything can only have a single type. The idiomatic way to do what you describe is to use a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), which can hold either a value or an error. This `Result` can be created with [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or):

```
pub fn unwrap_some_or_none_with_error(input: Option<&'static str>) -> Result<&str, i32> {
    input.ok_or(0)
}
```

Comment: Does `Result<&str, i32>` mean it expects both `&str` and `i32` in the Result returned ?

Comment: No, it means it expects _either_ an `&str` if all went well _or_ an `i32` in case of error.